# List not getting loaded correctly

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, abstract-class

I have a `Tax` abstract class

```
 public abstract class Tax
    {
        public  string TaxType;
        public  int TaxAmnt;
    }
```

It has properties (`TaxType`, `TaxAmnt`) and an abstract method (I have removed it as for now to fix this issue)

I have 2 derived classes - `BasicSalesTax`, `ImportTax` inheriting Tax

```
public class BasicSalesTax : Tax
    {
        public string TaxType;
        public int TaxAmnt;
        public BasicSalesTax():base()
        {
            this.TaxType = "BasicSalesTax";
            this.TaxAmnt = 10;
        }
    }
```

In my `main.cs`, I want to create a list `Taxlist` which contains all taxes.

```
List<Tax> objTaxlist = new List<Tax>();
BasicSalesTax objtax1 = new BasicSalesTax();

objtaxlist.Add(objtax1);
```

`objtaxlist` is getting added with 1 item , but its properties are null & 0 respectively.
how can I fix this??

When I debug, `objtax1` gets loaded correctly. I can see it attributes correctly.
But when I view the contents of `objtaxlist` , I see the `attirbutes` as null & 0.

Comment: Could you post the code to the abstract `Tax` class? Do you have any code in its constructor?

Comment: The list is irrelevant in diagnosing why the properties of your single object `objtax1` are not retaining their constructed values. I'd start by debugging that through each constructor call.

Comment: You are hiding the properties in the base class (assuming that `Tax` has properties `TaxType` and `TaxAmnt`). Use the `override` keyword.

Comment: what is this "BasicSalesTax() objtax1 = new basicsalestax();"

Comment: @KCdod I guess it's just a typo and should be `BasicSalesTax objtax1 = new BasicSalesTax ();`

Comment: @odyss-jii I think you mean the `new` keyword. Although in this case it's likely that the properties in `BasicSalesTax` aren't needed at all.

Comment: @Yuck: No, the `new` keyword is just an explicit hide, which is done implicitly otherwise unless the `override` keyword is used. That exactly what he shouldn't be doing :)  I'm guessing that he has the properties `TaxType` and `TaxAmnt` defined on the base-class, so he should either leave them out or override them if they are abstract.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the problem is that you're hiding your base class fields.

When both your base class and your derived class have the same name, without the `override`/`virtual` modifiers, then these are effectively two *different* fields:

```
class Base
{
     public int Amount = 0;
}

class Derived : Base
{
     public int Amount = 10;
}

void Main()
{  
    Derived d = new Derived();
    Console.WriteLine(d.Amount); // should print 10.
    Base b = d;
    Console.WriteLine(b.Amount); // should print 0.
}
```

This is because when you're accessing the object as `Derived`, you're accessing the `Derived.Amount` field, but when you're accessing via Base, you're accessing the separate `Base.Amount` field. Your compiler should have issued a warning that you're hiding an inherited field.

When inheriting, you don't need to redefine the inherited fields. They're automatically a part of the derived type:

```
class Base
{
     public int Amount = 0;
}

class Derived : Base
{
     public Derived() // You don't need to explicitly call base().
     {
         Amount = 10;
     }
}

void Main()
{  
    Derived d = new Derived();
    Console.WriteLine(d.Amount); // should print 10.
    Base b = d;
    Console.WriteLine(b.Amount); // should print 10 as well.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just get rid of `TaxType` and `TaxAmnt` form the `BasicSalesTax` definition so you will use the benefits of inheritance.

Alternatively (that is with your present implementation) to access hidden properties you have to cast the item from the list to the actual type.

```
var res = (BasicSalesTax)objTaxlist[0];
```

By casting you "unwrap" the object from general type (`Tax`) to a specific type (`BasicSalesTax`) and you exposing the properties of that specific type. Previously, they have been hidden by the general type.

Still, instead of patching object access of the incorrectly implemented type hierarchy it's better to fix the type implementation in the first place.